# Quantifier in Set definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

Can the definition be made more readable:

$\overline{R_1} = \{ (j_1,j_2)\mid j_2 < j_1 + \Gamma^r_a + c^r_w \text{ and }  j_1 \in J^r_v \text{ and }   j_2 \in J^r_v \text{ and }  a = (v,w) \in A^r \text{ and }  w \neq D^r \text{ for some } r \in R\}$

Comment: Where do $j_1$ and $j_2$ live? You have an informal set definition that's missing some context. And what's $j$ on the right? Did you intend to include the subscripts or is this some other variable?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’re written doesn’t quite make sense. I suspect that what you want is

$$\left\{\left(j^{r_1},j^{r_2}\right):\exists w\in R\setminus\{D\}\,\big((r_1,r_2)\in w\text{ and }j^{r_1}<j^{r_2}\big)\right\}$$

or, without the quantifier but with more words,

$$\left\{\left(j^{r_1},j^{r_2}\right):j^{r_1}<j^{r_2}\text{ and }(r_1,r_2)\in w\text{ for some }w\in R\setminus\{D\}\right\}\;.$$

This can also be written

$$\left\{\left(j^{r_1},j^{r_2}\right):(r_1,r_2)\in\bigcup\left(R\setminus\{D\}\right)\text{ and }j^{r_1}<j^{r_2}\big)\right\}\;,$$

since $(r_1,r_2)\in\bigcup\left(R\setminus\{D\}\right)$ if and only if there is a $w\in R\setminus\{D\}$ such that $(r_1,r_2)\in w$.

**Added:** For your set $\overline{R_1}$ you can write

$$\overline{R_1}=\left\{(j_1,j_2):\exists r\in R\,\exists a=(v,w)\in A^r\Big(w\ne D^r\mathrel{\&}j_1,j_2\in J_v^r\mathrel{\&}j_2<j_1+\Gamma_a^r+c_w^r\Big)\right\}\;.$$

Comment: Do you always have to use "and" to link these inclusion? For example if you  have $a \in b$, $b \in c $, $c \in d$, $d \in e$. Do i have to write then something like $\exists d \in e (c \in d  \text{ and } b \in c  \text{ and } a \in b \text{ and } j^a < j^b)$?

Comment: @hansimglueck: If you want to say that $a\in b,b\in c,c\in d$, and $d\in e$, then you can say simply $a\in b\in c\in d\in e$. Whether it makes any sense to say that there is a $d\in e$ such that $a\in b\in c\in d$ and $j^a<j^b$ depends on what these objects are.

Comment: ok but in your answer above is it ok to replace the "and" by a comma (,) or would that make it incorrect?

Comment: @hansimglueck: It makes the expression harder to read. Most readers would probably interpret it correctly, but why make life unnecessarily difficult? There’s nothing wrong with using a few words to make life easier. If you absolutely insist on getting rid of the word *and*, replace it with $\&$ or $\land$, symbols commonly used in logic for *and*.

Comment: The problem is that i have a very long expression, which fits into one line, when using , and i find it easier to read it with , instead of 7x "and" in (in then two lines).

Comment: @hansimglueck: Why don’t you modify your question to show exactly what you want to express? There may be other ways to shorten it.

Comment: @hansimglueck: See if what I’ve added to my answer serves your purpose. I used `\Big(` and `\Big)` for greater readability, but you could shrink them if you wished.

Comment: thanks! it looks much better!

Comment: @hansimglueck: You’re welcome. I just realized that it’s a little bit wrong: somehow I missed the fact that the indices $r$ and $v$ on $J$ depend on what’s to the right of the colon. Give me a moment to fix that; it’ll still be quite compact.